# Print item from list in chunks of 50 in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list with 2,500 items. I want to print the first 50 items in a line and the next 50 items in the next line. So there will be a total of 50 lines with 50 items in each line.

```
myList = ['item1', item2,..., 'item2500'] 

line1 = item1, item2, ..., item50
line2 = item51, item52,...., item100
.
.
line 50 = item2451, item2452,...., item 2500
```

Tried some while loops but it didn't quite work out. Is there a built-in functions or an easier way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just print the list with next 50 items on the next line:

```
for i in range(0, len(myList), 50):
     print myList[i:i+50]
```

If you want to make a list of lists with 50-len chunks:

```
[myList[i:i+50] for i in range(0, len(myList), 50)]
```

Comment: n=50 in your comprehension, right?

Answer (score 3):

Same thing really, but looks nicer and reusable chunks function as a generator, I think.

```
def chunks_of_n(l,n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

def show_my_list_in_chunks(l):
    for chunk in chunks_of_n(l,50):
        print ', '.join(l)
```

Comment: +1, generators are always pretty.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary instead of actually creating variables like this.

As an example, I have a list of numbers 1-10 that I will split up into fives:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> it = iter(L)
>>> d = {}
>>> chunk = 2
>>> for i in xrange(1, 6):
...     d['item{}'.format(i)] = list(islice(it, chunk))
... 
>>> print d
{'item2': [3, 4], 'item3': [5, 6], 'item1': [1, 2], 'item4': [7, 8], 'item5': [9, 10]}
```

So in your example, you would set `chunk = 50` and `xrange(1, 51)`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I've used izip and made `chunks` return a generator. I've never used islice, so I'll look into it, thanks :D

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I think I improperly used `islice`, could you please check?

Comment: Something like this : http://codepad.org/OO8ASXz6

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ['thing'+str(i+1) for i in xrange(2500)]
for i in xrange(0,len(mylist),50):
    print mylist[i:i+50]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the absolutely impractical and esoteric response with closures

```
def chunkify(l, step):
     def f():
         f.x += 1
         return l[f.x*step:(f.x+1)*step]
     f.x = -1
     return f
```

Example usage:

```
>>> a = [i for i in range(2500)]
>>> chunks = chunkify(a, 50)
>>> chunks()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
>>> chunks()
[51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]
>>> chunks()
[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a loop with just mod 50 would essentially do what you want. I don't really know Python, but something along the lines of FizzBuzz almost would do it:

```
i = 0
..loop through
print an_item
if (i % 50) == 0:
   print "\n"
..end loop
```

Comment: This doesn't accomplish the desired behavior in Python.  Each call to print will automatically print to a new line.  This would work if you were using C++'s `cout` without `endl` or `<<"\n";` though.